# Error with find the longest word in a string task(javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm using freecodecamp.com and the task is to find the longest word in a string, I'm getting this error and I can't work out why I have looked at other projects as well.

> "TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference"

It is referring to the `copy[i].length`

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var copy = str;
  copy = copy.split(' ');
  var longest = 0;
  for (var i = 0;i < copy.length;i++);
  {
    if (longest < copy[i].length)
      {
        longest = copy[i].length;
      }
  }
  return longest;
}
findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You had a semi colon after your for loop.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var copy = str;
  copy = copy.split(' ');
  var longest = 0;
  for (var i = 0;i < copy.length;i++)
  {
    if (longest < copy[i].length)
      {
        longest = copy[i].length;
      }
  }
  return longest;
}
var l = findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
console.log('Longest = ' + l);
```

Comment: That is so frustrating ha, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you had a semi colon `;` on your for loop line

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
      
      var copy = str.split(' ');
      var longest = 0;
      var index =0;
      for (var i = 0;i < copy.length;i++)
      {
        if (longest < copy[i].length)
          {
            longest = copy[i].length;
            index=i;
          }
      }
      console.log("longest word is " +copy[index]);
      return longest;
    }
    
    console.log('longest word length = '+findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qn6g62zt/2/) link is here.